# python mox assert that a module function raises an exception

Tags: python, mox

How do I make sure that a certain function raises an exception on certain inputs using `mox`?

I could do it with try catch but it doesn't seem like too `mox`xy

Lets say the function is the following:

```
def merge_paths(a, b):
   if a == "":
      raise RuntimeError("Wrong prefix")
   return a+b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havne't used `mox` before, but looking at the documentation I guess you're just using this with `unittest` module?

If so you can do it using [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)

```
self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, merge_paths, a="", b="b")
```

(`self` being an instance of `unittest.TestCase`)

In fact in the first usage example in the [mox documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pymox/wiki/MoxDocumentation#General_Usage_Example) there is an example of `assertRaises`.

Comment: I stumbled across every other documentation, but not this one. Thanks!